# Query, subquery and using as variables from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Is it not possible to use the "as [item] and then use the item variable in the query.

For example:

```
select c.category as [category],c.orderby as [CatOrder], m.masterno, m.master
,-- select OUT (select count(*) from    rentalitem       ri  with (nolock), 
            rentalitemstatus ris with (nolock), 
            rentalstatus     rs  with (nolock)
    where   ri.rentalitemid    = ris.rentalitemid
            and   ris.rentalstatusid = rs.rentalstatusid
            and   ri.masterid        = m.masterid
            and   rs.statustype     in ('OUT', 'INTRANSIT', 'ONTRUCK'))  as [qtyout] 
,-- select OWNED owned=
(select top 1 mwq.qty                                           
    from    masterwhqty mwq                                              
    where   mwq.masterid    = m.masterid) 

, -([owned]-[qtyout]) as [Variance]

from master m 
    inner join category c on c.categoryid=m.categoryid and c.categoryid=@category
    inner join inventorydepartment d on c.inventorydepartment=@department
```

I cannot seem to use qtyout or owned when calculating variance. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a table variable and then reference that table variable like you are trying to do above....here's an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
    EmpID int NOT NULL,
    OldVacationHours int,
    NewVacationHours int,
    ModifiedDate datetime);
UPDATE TOP (10) HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = VacationHours * 1.25,
    ModifiedDate = GETDATE() 
OUTPUT inserted.BusinessEntityID,
       deleted.VacationHours,
       inserted.VacationHours,
       inserted.ModifiedDate
INTO @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT EmpID, OldVacationHours, NewVacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM @MyTableVar;
GO
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT TOP (10) BusinessEntityID, VacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

need to move your calculated fields into a subquery, and then use them by their alias in the outer query.

```
select subquery.*, -([owned]-[qtyout]) as [Variance]
from
(
    select c.category as [category],c.orderby as [CatOrder], m.masterno, m.master
    ,-- select OUT (select count(*) from    rentalitem       ri  with (nolock), 
                rentalitemstatus ris with (nolock), 
                rentalstatus     rs  with (nolock)
        where   ri.rentalitemid    = ris.rentalitemid
                and   ris.rentalstatusid = rs.rentalstatusid
                and   ri.masterid        = m.masterid
                and   rs.statustype     in ('OUT', 'INTRANSIT', 'ONTRUCK'))  as [qtyout] 
    ,-- select OWNED owned=
    (select top 1 mwq.qty                                           
        from    masterwhqty mwq                                              
        where   mwq.masterid    = m.masterid) as [owned]

    from master m 
        inner join category c on c.categoryid=m.categoryid and c.categoryid=@category
        inner join inventorydepartment d on c.inventorydepartment=@department
) as subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       ([owned]-[qtyout]) as [Variance]
from (<something like your query here
     ) t
```

You query, even without the comments, doesn't quite make sense (`select OUT (select . . .` for isntance).  But, the answer to your question is to define the base variables in a subquery or CTE and then subsequently use them.

And, you are calling the difference "variance".  Just so you know, you are redefining the statistical meaning of the term (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), which is based on the squares of the differences.